# How to join most recent currency exchange date on a date which falls on a weekend or holiday?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with transactions with different currencies, and some of these dates fall on a weekend or holiday. Example:

```
Date       currency_code    ammount
20-02-2017 EUR              55
18-02-2017 GBP              33
17-02-2017 EUR              44.55
```

An example of what my `Currency` table looks like:

```
SELECT rate,date, currency_code FROM exchangeTable:

rate      Date          currency_code
53,35     13-02-2017    ADP   
53,35     14-02-2017    ADP    
182,4     16-02-2017    ADP    
192,45    17-02-2017    ADP    
191,31    20-02-2017    ADP
```

Is there a simple subquery I can use in my join statement which will join the most recent currency date onto my transaction date, if it falls on a weekend or holiday? I think I should use a partition here, but don't have much experience with them.

```
left join (?????????) a on a.date = b.date and a.currency_code= b.currency_code
```

Comment: Have you tried including a `WHERE` clause at the end? Something like `WHERE a.Date = b.Date`?

Comment: Replace ??????? with a GROUP BY query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to `JOIN` all rows form the `Currency` table with the same `CurrencyCode`, then you can use the `RANK() PARTITION (...` function to select the one with the most  recent date compared to the transaction's date.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        t.*,
        c.*,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(d, t.[Date], c.[Date])) ASC, c.[Date] DESC) rn
    FROM
        Transactions t
    INNER JOIN
        Currency c ON t.CurrencyCode = c.CurrencyCode) t
WHERE
    t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a derived table, `ROW_NUMBER`, and partitions. What this does is eliminate weekends using the `DATEPART` function with the `dw` (day of week) argument to ignore any Saturday and Sunday. For holidays, you'll have to have a table of holiday dates since holidays are entirely subjective.

`ROW_NUMBER` allows you to get an index of the row number given a custom ordering and partition. We partition by currency so the index resets every time we hit a new currency, and we order by `DATE DESC` so the most recent date for each currency is `1`.

```
-- create a sample table with the date, currency, and exchange rate
create table rates (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    date date not null,
    currency char(3) not null,
    rate decimal(10,2) not null
)
go

-- create table of holidays we'll use for excluding rates records later
create table holidays (
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    date date not null,
    name varchar(100) not null
)

-- create some sample data
-- Feb 18 and 19 are Saturday and Sunday
insert into rates (date, currency, rate) values
('2017-02-16', 'GBP', 1.23),
('2017-02-17', 'GBP', 1.24),
('2017-02-18', 'GBP', 1.25),
('2017-02-19', 'GBP', 1.26),
('2017-02-20', 'GBP', 1.27),
('2017-02-16', 'SGD', 2.23),
('2017-02-17', 'SGD', 2.24),
('2017-02-18', 'SGD', 2.25),
('2017-02-19', 'SGD', 2.26),
('2017-02-20', 'SGD', 2.27);

insert into holidays (date, name) values
('2017-02-20', 'National Cherry Pie Day'); -- this is a real thing


with t as (
    select id,
           date,
           currency,
           rate,
           row_number() over (partition by currency order by date desc) as age
    from   rates
    where  datepart(dw, date) not in (1, 7) -- sunday, saturday
           and date not in (select date from holidays) -- exclude holiday rates
)
select * from t where age = 1;
```