# MySql : Is there any better way to link transaction table with currency exchange table to get corresponding exchange rate

Tags: mysql, transactions, common-table-expression, currency, currency-exchange-rates

Is there any better way (performance wise) to link transactions with currency exchange table where the transaction table has more than a million records ?

**tabTran**

| date | amount | currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 100 | GBP |
| 2023-01-05 | 200 | INR |
| 2023-01-07 | 150 | EUR |
| 2023-01-13 | 50 | INR |
| 2023-01-15 | 100 | GBP |

**tabCurrency_Exchange**

| date | from_curr | to_curr | exch_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-25 | AED | USD | 0.276495000 |
| 2022-12-28 | AED | USD | 0.276495000 |
| 2022-12-28 | PLN | USD | 0.226435000 |
| 2022-12-30 | EUR | USD | 1.170000000 |
| 2023-01-02 | AED | USD | 0.277130000 |
| 2023-01-02 | PLN | USD | 0.228550000 |
| 2023-01-05 | PLN | USD | 0.228550000 |
| 2023-01-05 | EUR | USD | 0.971758000 |
| 2023-01-06 | EUR | USD | 1.089531680 |
| 2023-01-10 | PLN | USD | 1.089531680 |
| 2023-01-10 | EUR | USD | 0.235714280 |
| 2023-01-14 | AED | USD | 0.272521000 |
| 2023-01-15 | AED | USD | 0.276495000 |
| 2023-01-15 | PLN | USD | 0.228571400 |

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabTran ENGINE=MEMORY  AS (
    SELECT '2023-01-01' `date`, 100 amount, 'AED' currency
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-05', 200, 'PLN'
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-07', 159, 'EUR'
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-13', 50, 'PLN'
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-15', 100, 'AED'
);
    
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabCurrency_Exchange ENGINE=MEMORY  AS (
    SELECT '2022-12-25' `date`, 'AED' from_curr, 'USD' to_curr, 0.276495000 exch_rate
    UNION SELECT '2022-12-28', 'AED', 'USD', 0.276495000 
    UNION SELECT '2022-12-28', 'PLN', 'USD', 0.226435000 
    UNION SELECT '2022-12-30', 'EUR', 'USD', 1.170000000 
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-02', 'AED', 'USD', 0.277130000 
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-02', 'PLN', 'USD', 0.228550000 
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-05', 'PLN', 'USD', 0.228550000 
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-05', 'EUR', 'USD', 0.971758000 
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-06', 'EUR', 'USD', 1.089531680 
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-10', 'PLN', 'USD', 1.089531680 
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-10', 'EUR', 'USD', 0.235714280 
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-14', 'AED', 'USD', 0.272521000 
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-15', 'AED', 'USD', 0.276495000 
    UNION SELECT '2023-01-15', 'PLN', 'USD', 0.228571400 
);
```

**expected result**

| date | amount | currency | to_curr | exch_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 100 | AED | USD | 0.276495000 |
| 2023-01-05 | 200 | PLN | USD | 0.228550000 |
| 2023-01-07 | 150 | EUR | USD | 1.089531680 |
| 2023-01-13 | 50 | PLN | USD | 1.089531680 |
| 2023-01-15 | 100 | AED | USD | 0.276495000 |

**what I tried**

```
select `date`, amount, currency, 'USD' to_curr, 
(
    select exch_rate from tabCurrency_Exchange where 
    from_curr = tabTran.currency
    and to_curr = 'USD'
    and `date` <= tabTran.date
    order by `date` desc
    limit 1
) exch_rate
from tabTran;
```

**checked previous posts**
[Multiple Currency Conversions in Single Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328154/multiple-currency-conversions-in-single-query)
[Select Exchange Rate based on Currency and Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824773/select-exchange-rate-based-on-currency-and-date)
[How to join most recent currency exchange date on a date which falls on a weekend or holiday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340847/how-to-join-most-recent-currency-exchange-date-on-a-date-which-falls-on-a-weeken)
[Joining Exchange rate with a currency table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289924/joining-exchange-rate-with-a-currency-table)

Comment: Your code looks fine. For performance, consider adding an index on `tabCurrency_Exchange (from_curr, to_curr, date desc, exch_rate)` maybe.